# How to print a list as list of list in particular order in Python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, indexing

Return list given below in list of 3 element lists in python-3.x

**input**: `l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

I am expecting this output:

**Output**: `l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure your question makes any sense to begin with -- how do you expect that output from that input? It seems pretty arbitrary to me.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but that day I didn't know about slicing, sorry to bother,
here it is:
`l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];l=[[l[i],l[i+1],l[i+2]] for i in range(0,9,3)];print(L)`